# TodoList in Symfony 3

Tags: php, to-do-list, yaml, doctrine, symfony3

This little project is about working with doctrine Entity object and everything is working fine.

This is my first project in Symfony 3. Please review my service file and give me some advice to improve it. My main concern is lack of error handling.

**service.yml**

```
parameters:

services:

      app.ToDoList:
        class: AppBundle\Utils\ToDoList
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
```

**Service file**

```
<?php


namespace AppBundle\Utils;
use AppBundle\Entity\test;

class ToDoList
{
    private $doctrineManager;

    public function __construct($em)
    {
        $this->doctrineManager = $em;
    }

    public function insert($array){
        if(!isset($array['name'])){return false;}

        $task = new test();
        $task->setName($array['name']);
        $task->setDate(new \DateTime());
        if(isset($array['description'])){
            $task->setDescription($array['description']);
        }
        $this->doctrineManager->persist($task);
        $this->doctrineManager->flush();

        return true;
    }

    public function get(){
        $all = $this->doctrineManager->getRepository('AppBundle:test')->findAll();
        if($all==null) {return false;}

        $json = $this->transformIntoJson($all);
        return $json;
    }
    public function getOne($id){
        $one = $this->doctrineManager->getRepository('AppBundle:test')->findOneById($id);
        if($one==null) {return false;}

        $arr[]=$one;
        $json = $this->transformIntoJson($arr);
        return $json;
    }

    public function transformIntoJson($arr){
        $table = [];
        foreach($arr as $value){
            $field = new \stdClass();
            $field->id = $value->getId();
            $field->name = $value->getName();
            $field->description = $value->getDescription();
            array_push($table,$field);
        }
        $table = json_encode($table);
        return $table;
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $one = $this->doctrineManager->getRepository('AppBundle:test')->findOneById($id);
        if($one==null){return false;}

        $this->doctrineManager->remove($one);
        $this->doctrineManager->flush();
        return true;

    }
}
```

**Controller file**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;


use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ToDoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/insert"), name="InsertIntoTable")
     */
    public function insertToList(){
            $test = $this->get("app.todolist")->insert(["name"=>"TaskName",
                                                        "description"=>"TaskDecription"]);
            if($test == true){
                $response = "Task inserted succesfully"; }else{
                $response = "Error";
            }
            return new Response($response);
        }
    /**
     * @Route("/"), name="AllTasks")
     */
    public function getAll(){
       if ($tasks = $this->get("app.todolist")->get()){
           return new Response($tasks);
       }else{
           return new Response("0 tasks");
       }
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/{id}"), name="One task")
     */
    public function getOne($id){
        if($task = $this->get("app.todolist")->getOne($id)){
            return new Response($task);
        }else{
            return new Response("There is no such task");
        }
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/delete/{id}"), name="Dlete task")
     */
    public function delete($id){
        if($task = $this->get("app.todolist")->delete($id)){
            return new Response("Task was deleted succesfully");
        }else{
            return new Response("There are no task with that number");
        }
    }
}
```

**Entity file - created by doctrine**

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * test
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="test")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\testRepository")
 */
class test
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $date;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     *
     * @return test
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return test
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set date
     *
     * @param \DateTime $date
     *
     * @return test
     */
    public function setDate($date)
    {
        $this->date = $date;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get date
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `Service` for this task? In your example your setting the values hard coded, but I assume that these will submitted by a request later. Why don't you use a `FormType`, that will also handle `Constraints` for each form field corresponding to your class members?

Answer (score 3):

1. It's better to user `snake_case` for service names. so it's better to be `app.to_do_list`
2. I prefer adding `now` when using `new \Datetime()`; it's more readable.
3. Instead of `get` method you can call it `getAll`.
4. You can create a new service and move the `transformIntoJson` method there and add it as a dependency to your class.
5. Use `snake_case` for action names. like `all_tasks` instead of `AllTasks`

and please follow [PSR-*](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) coding styles.

Answer (score 2):

You can omit `else` in most cases:

```
/**
 * @Route("/"), name="AllTasks")
 */
public function getAll(){
   if ($tasks = $this->get("app.todolist")->get()){
       return new Response($tasks);
   }

   return new Response("0 tasks");
}
```

Use a FCQN as service id and you can omit the `class`. And if you use `autowire` you can omit the arguments too:

```
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
  AppBundle\Utils\ToDoList: ~
```

In your controller:

```
$test = $this->get(ToDoList::class)->insert(...
```

See

- [New in Symfony 3.3: Optional class for named services](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-optional-class-for-named-services)
- [New in Symfony 2.8: Service Auto Wiring](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-8-service-auto-wiring)

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Use Exceptions for Errors

Instead of returning false, use exceptions. When code encounters an error, it can determine how to proceed, such as logging the error or notifying the user.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

public function getOne($id) {
    $item = $this->doctrineManager->getRepository('AppBundle:Test')->findOneById($id);
    if ($item === null) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Task not found');
    }
    return $item; // This means the method returns the item or some data.
}
```

### 2. Validate Data Early

It's important to validate data early to prevent issues later on. Symfony offers tools such as `Form` and `Validator` to assist.

Here's how you can check the data:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$constraint = new Assert\Collection([
    // Your rules here
    'name' => new Assert\Length(['min' => 3]),
    // Add more as needed
]);

$violations = $validator->validate($input, $constraint);

if (0 !== count($violations)) {
    // If there are errors, deal with them
    foreach ($violations as $violation) {
        // Log or return the errors
    }
}
```

#### 3. Logging Errors

It's a good idea to use `Monolog` to log errors in Symfony. You can customize it a lot. Adding `LoggerInterface` to your service lets you write down errors and other info where you want.

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

private $logger;

public function __construct($em, LoggerInterface $logger) {
    this->doctrineManager = $em;
    this->logger = $logger;
}

// In a method where an error might happen
$this->logger->error('An error occurred', ['error' => $error]);
```